# Best way to trigger an hour before event starts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, background-process, rake-task

I have many `Appointment` models that start at various times of the day, either at **:00, :15, :30, :45**. I'd like to trigger code to send a reminder **1 hour** before the event starts. What would be the best way to use a background worker to trigger this? I'm using the [clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) gem as well so I can schedule Sidekiq workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clockwork` gem is for fixed schedule jobs (a replacement for cron). You'll want to use `ActionMailer.delay_until` that comes with `sidekiq`:

```
class Appointment
  after_create :queue_reminder

  def queue_reminder
    MyMailer.delay_until(event_time - 1.hour).appointment_reminder(id)
  end
end
```

See `sidekiq` docs here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-Extensions

As shock_one mentioned, if you update an appointment with a new date, you'll have to requeue a reminder and cancel the old one. You'll also want to cancel a job if an `Appointment` is destroyed.

For that, I'd advise you use [`sidekiq-status`](https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status), and a `reminder_job_id` column. Your `Appointment` model would then look something like:

```
class Appointment
  before_save :queue_reminder, if: :event_time_changed?
  after_destroy :cancel_reminder, if: :reminder_job_id?

  def queue_reminder
    cancel_reminder if reminder_job_id
    self.reminder_job_id = MyMailer.delay_until(event_time - 1.hour)
                                   .appointment_reminder(id)
  end

  def cancel_reminder
    Sidekiq::Status.cancel reminder_job_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to decide who will be responsible for scheduling. You can either have a background process, which runs every fifteen minutes, or you can make the model schedule the event at some point of its life - probably after creation.

The former solution is simpler to understand and maintain, but the background process will have many useless empty loops.

On the other hand, the latter solution is more precise. It will be executed exactly as many times as required. However, it may have difficulties if the model changes: for example, the time has been modified after it was created. You'd need to cancel the previous event somehow, and schedule a new one.