# Whenever gem cronjob on a particular time based on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

I am using the whenever gem, to handle my cron jobs. 
I have an events and bookings rails application where I have an events and a bookings table.

I want to send out a mailer, with all the bookings for an event to the event organizer an hour or so before the event's start time. 
But I am not able to find a way to that with the whenever gem.

Currently, I am just sending out all mailers at 9pm, and that works perfectly, but I that doesn't serve my use case, since different event organizers require it at different times

Comment: Please consider sharing code, what have you tried or trying.

Comment: Try check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24077174/5239030), maybe can give some insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to run `whenever` dynamically. Just add this line to the top of your `schedule.rb`:

```
require "/home/username/appname/config/environment.rb"
```

That allows you to use all your models class on the schedule.rb. For example:

```
every 1.day, :at => (Booking.last.event_time - 1.hour).strftime('%I:%M %p') do
  ...
end
```

Also, you can use the environment variable to set the time too.

Don't forget update crontab when time change:

```
system 'bundle exec whenever --update-crontab'
```

But cron uses to run schedule jobs (commands or shell scripts) **periodically** at fixed times. So, whenever isn't better solution for you. As iGian wrote at his comment - check this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076954/best-way-to-trigger-an-hour-before-event-starts/24077174#24077174): delay job(sidekiq or similar) is more relevant to that job.

Comment: This works perfectly, only thing, the strftime format you provided didnt work for some reason. The format that worked for me was 

.strftime('%I:%M%P')

Answer (score 0):

@Leo answered it correctly, but adding `require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/environment")` at the beginning of your `schedule.rb` will make it more versatile and easier to read.